# Converting Str to Integer

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` on this line of code:

```
 a= doc['coordinates']['coordinates']
```

This is reading records from a db, I would like to know how to convert this into an integer from str?

Thanks

EDIT:

`doc['coordinates']['coordinates']` returns coordinate information from a mongoDB, where these are the fields. It returns the relevant information for the first ten times the program runs, then I get this error.

Comment: Is `coordinates` the variable in which you are storing record values?

Comment: Coordinates are a field in which I store longtitude and Latitude information

Comment: Looks like `doc['coordinates']` is returning a list.

Comment: Yes it returns this: [-86.31418053, 34.17126826]

Comment: so try `x,y=doc['coordinates']` then.

Comment: @user94628: well, then you have your coordinates, right? Why the second `['coordinates']`?

Comment: `x = int(string)` is certainly *not* what you want to be doing - you need to learn how to navigate a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at what is happening here:

```
a= doc['coordinates']['coordinates']
```

First `doc['coordinates']` is evaluated. This returns a list of coordinates, lets say `[32.9,23.11]`.

Now you're trying to look up something in this list with the index 'coordinates'.

`a = [32.9,32.11]['coordinates']`

This is your list: `[32.9,32.11]`

Lists only have numerical indices, in this case: `0` and `1`.

If you're trying to assign a list of coordinates to a variable, you could just do `a = doc['coordinates']` or if you want an individual coordinate, `doc['coordinates'][0]`